# How to increase height of image header in Infowindow?

Tags: carto, image, carto-js, infowindow

The CartoDB Infowindow default image header width is max 400, with height always set to a default, which looks to be about 250 so the image is really wide.

Is there a way to set the image to be more "square" let say 400x400 on the header or break the 400 max?

Comment: I have the same problem. I put the code you explained in CSS part of the layer. It doesn't work saying there is an error of Unrecognized rule: max-height.

Comment: you should add this as a comment to the answer, not as another answer; otherwise @xavijam may not see it

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to change the width or the height of the infowindow changing the CSS of it. For example, if you want to change the height of the image header:

```
div.cartodb-popup.header.with-image {
   max-height: 300px
}
```